# Error no element found while running Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

Hey I'm just starting out on ROS. I'm trying to run my gazebo file but it keeps on throwing the following error: `no element found in line 8`. Below is the code:

```
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import PathJoinSubstitution
import os
import xacro
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


def generate_launch_description():
    share_dir = get_package_share_directory('sid_agv_description')

    xacro_file = os.path.join(share_dir, 'urdf', 'sid_agv.xacro')
    robot_description_config = xacro.process_file(xacro_file)
    robot_urdf = robot_description_config.toxml()

    robot_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        name='robot_state_publisher',
        parameters=[
            {'robot_description': robot_urdf}
        ]
    )

    joint_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        name='joint_state_publisher'
    )

    gazebo_server = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([
            PathJoinSubstitution([
                FindPackageShare('gazebo_ros'),
                'launch',
                'gzserver.launch.py'
            ])
        ]),
        launch_arguments={
            'pause': 'true'
        }.items()
    )

    gazebo_client = IncludeLaunchDescription(
        PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([
            PathJoinSubstitution([
                FindPackageShare('gazebo_ros'),
                'launch',
                'gzclient.launch.py'
            ])
        ])
    )

    urdf_spawn_node = Node(
        package='gazebo_ros',
        executable='spawn_entity.py',
        arguments=[
            '-entity', 'sid_agv',
            '-topic', 'robot_description'
        ],
        output='screen'
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        robot_state_publisher_node,
        joint_state_publisher_node,
        gazebo_server,
        gazebo_client,
        urdf_spawn_node,
    ])
```

Upon running, it shows the following error:

```
[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught exception when trying to load file of format [py]: no element found: line 8, column 8
```